# Cannot push into angularJS array

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I am trying to push data into an array in angularJS.  But neither `$scope.array.push(data)` nor `$scope.array[$scope.array.length] = data` are working.

My app is basically a form with multiple steps.  I want to be able to keep track of the steps taken by the user (there are many variants) so that if they want to go back a step, I know where I'm sending them.

In my App I have these variables set up

```
$scope.stepHistory = [];
$scope.step =0;
```

Then when they hit 'Next' I'm firing this function below and setting the step number to whatever the new step is (which is working).

```
$scope.setStepHistory = function() {
  $scope.stepHistory.push($scope.step);
}
```

But `.push()` is not adding anything to the array.

I'm doing lots of other things with angular in this app and it is all set up correctly.

Comment: have you tried to call $scope.$apply() ; after you push data to your array ?

Comment: are you doing all this in the same controller?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with what you have here, there must be something else going on...

Comment: It's also working in this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/PbmEmsLHD7XDe2AH3OeM?p=preview so the problem must be somewhere else

Comment: Please provide demo that replicates the problem

Comment: OK.  Figured it out.  I had another function running all the time that got the stepHistory and removed the last element, so by the time I ran this function it had always had the last element removed.  Only took a few hours to figure out!